# change color in xml from shared preference

Tags: android, xml, colors, sharedpreferences

I am saving colors in Shared Preference. I am able to change colors in Activity from Shared Preference. Is there any way I can change Color in my XML file using Shared preference or anything else. The color will be runtime and will come from the web end.

Setting Color in Preference-

```
SPColorSetting.setValue(this,SPColorSetting.color_primary,"#71b280")
```

Getting color from Preference-

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(SPColorSetting.getValue(HomeNavigationDrawerActivity.this,SPColorSetting.color_primary)));
```

Comment: No, you'll have to do that in code.

Comment: Can't change xml values from code

Comment: I have some drawable and gradients, I need to change Color runtime.